# Transfering data from SQL Server to PostgreSQL using GDAL

Tags: postgis, gdal, sql, database

I am new to GDAL and have been uploading CSV crime data to a PostGIS database using ogr2ogr.

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geometry -lco FID=gid PG:"host=server user=user dbname=dbname password=****" C:\Users\TommyH\Desktop\csv_upload_postgres.vrt -nln th_crime_2017 -t_srs EPSG:27700
```

Is there a way to transfer data from PostGIS to SQL Server or Oracle using GDAL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GDAL ogr2ogr script I used to transfer data between databases is as followed.

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -update -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=databasename user=postgres password=*******" -f MSSQLSpatial "MSSQL:server=server;database=SUPPORT;UID=support;PWD=******" support.TEST -lco OVERWRITE=yes -lco SCHEMA=public  -a_srs EPSG:27700 -progress
```

Comment: I believe there is an error in the accepted answer provided by Hutch.
You cannot pass twice the `-f` parameter in a single ogr2ogr call, as it is [the Output file format name](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html). If you simply remove the second `-f`, before "MSSQLSpatial", it should be okay.